# Refrescar página y mantener los datos de formulario

Tags: javascript

Hice un formulario que guarde los registros en la misma página, pero al recargar la página, estos registros se borran. Lo que quiero hacer es que al recargar la página (o salirme) estos datos se queden guardados.

Este es el código del form:

```javascript
document.querySelector("input[class=agregar]").addEventListener("click",function(e){
    // cancelamos el evento submit
    e.preventDefault();
 
    var nombre=document.querySelector("input[name=nombre]");
    var edad=document.querySelector("input[name=edad]");
    var movimiento = document.querySelector("input[name=movimiento");
    // mostramos un error si no ha recibido el nombre
    if(!nombre.value)
    {
        nombre.classList.add("error");
        return;
    }
    nombre.classList.remove("error");
 
    // mostramos un error si no ha recibido una edad
    if(isNaN(parseInt(edad.value)) || parseInt(edad.value)<=0)
    {
        edad.classList.add("error");
        return;
    }
    edad.classList.remove("error");
    // mostramos un error si no ha recibido el movimiento
    if (!movimiento.value) {
        movimiento.classList.add("error");
        return;
    }
    movimiento.classList.remove("error");
 
    // añadimos el alumno a la tabla crando el tr, td's y el botón para eliminarlo
    var tr=document.createElement("tr");
 
    var tdNombre=document.createElement("td");
    var txt=document.createTextNode(nombre.value);
    tdNombre.appendChild(txt);
    tdNombre.className="nombre";
 
    var tdEdad=document.createElement("td");
    txt=document.createTextNode(edad.value);
    tdEdad.appendChild(txt);
    tdEdad.className="right";
 

    var tdMovimiento = document.createElement("td");
    var txt = document.createTextNode(movimiento.value);
    tdMovimiento.appendChild(txt);
    tdMovimiento.className = "movimiento";

    var tdRemove=document.createElement("td");
    var buttonRemove=document.createElement("input")
    buttonRemove.type="button";
    buttonRemove.value="Eliminar";
    buttonRemove.onclick=function () {
        // elimina la columna
        this.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
 
        // Si no hay ningun alumno, escondemos la tabla
        if(document.getElementById("listado").querySelector("tbody").querySelectorAll("tr").length==0)
        {
            document.getElementById("listado").classList.add("hide");
        }
    };
    tdRemove.appendChild(buttonRemove);
 
    tr.appendChild(tdNombre);
    tr.appendChild(tdEdad);
    tr.appendChild(tdMovimiento);
    tr.appendChild(tdRemove);
 
    var tbody=document.getElementById("listado").querySelector("tbody").appendChild(tr);
 
    // eliminamos la clase que tiene oculta la tabla cando no hay ningun alumno
    document.getElementById("listado").classList.remove("hide");
 
    //limpiamos los valores del input
    edad.value="";
    nombre.value="";
    nombre.focus();
    movimiento.value = "";
    movimiento.focus();
 
});
```

Comment: Talvez estas utilizando alguna biblioteca en especifico???. De lo contrario revisa como guardar en LocalStorage para almacenar en el navegador. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Dependiendo del tipo de datos que quieras guardar puedes hacerlo de una manera u otra, si NO son datos sensibles podrías usar `localStorage` para almacenar esos datos o inclusive las cookies tradicionales.

Comment: muchisimas gracias!!, lo intentare, de verdad gracias por su ayuda!! ʕ•́ᴥ•̀ʔっ♥

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te doy un ejemplo:

La función del listener `keyup` consiste en intentar capturar el valor del `localstorage` para eliminarla y poner el último valor que escribas en el input, de esta forma capturas y envías el último texto que escribas en tu input, ya que la función se ejecuta cada vez que escribes en el formulario, y al recargar la página, capturas el valor final del `localstorage` y lo asignas como el valor del input:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('texto');

// cuando escriba en el input, escucho al evento "keyup" y ejecutamos la función
input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  const textoGuardado = localStorage.getItem('textoGuardado'); // capturo el texto del localstorage...
  if (textoGuardado) { // y si encuentra...
    localStorage.removeItem('textoGuardado'); // remuevo ese texto.
  }
  const texto = input.value; // luego capturo el texto actual del input...
  localStorage.setItem('textoGuardado', texto); // y envío ese valor del input al localstorage.
});

// al recargar la página, escucho al evento "load" y ejecutamos la función
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  // capturo al texto del localstorage
  const textoGuardado = localStorage.getItem('textoGuardado');
  // y si encuentra...
  if (textoGuardado) {
    input.value = textoGuardado; // el valor del input será ese valor obtenido del localstorage
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="texto">
```

Y si son varios inputs, entonces capturas todos los `inputs`, los recorres con `forEach` y a cada input le agregas su valor al `localstorage` diferenciándolos por su `id`, es decir, el input con id `texto1` tendrá un valor almacenado en el `localstorage`, el `texto2` también, sucesivamente, así nunca se repiten, ejemplo:

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');

inputs.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    const textoGuardado = localStorage.getItem(input.id);
    if (textoGuardado) {
      localStorage.removeItem(input.id);
    }
    const texto = input.value;
    localStorage.setItem(input.id, texto);
  });
  
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const textoGuardado = localStorage.getItem(input.id);
    if (textoGuardado) {
      input.value = textoGuardado;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="texto1">
<input type="text" id="texto2">
<input type="text" id="texto3">
```

Te adjunto una [**demo**](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/VwGEbvr).

Prueba escribiendo en los inputs y recargar la página, verás que los textos se mantienen (en incógnito no funciona, extrañamente).

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad por ayudarme, lo probare!! ʕ•́ᴥ•̀ʔっ♡